# CSS-Grid: How to align 2 left, one large in the middle and two right?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am struggling to get what I want and I am not sure if its even possible.

Tried everything I got, showing some code below

```css
section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}

section > *{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

section > h1{
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

section > h2{
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

section > img{
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    width: 20%;
}

section > span{
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 3 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    <h1>HEADING</h1>
    <img src=img.png alt="">
    <h2>HEADING 2</h2>
    <span>11:44</span>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>HEADING</h1>
    <img src=img.png alt="">
    <h2>HEADING 2</h2>
    <span>11:44</span>
  </section>
  ...
</div>
```

I want the image to appear left, using the upper and lower cell, so full height.

I want the h1 to use the upper center space.

I want the h2 to use the lower center space.

i want the span to use the upper right space.

The lower right space should be combined with the lowercenter in case the content of lowercenter overflows.

Comment: I know, but i always end up that the h2 appears below all other elements.

Comment: css edited above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there but there were some issues.

You defined a **four** column grid but your description only requires **three**.

```
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr; /* (seems more appropriate) /*
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr;
}

section>* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

section>h1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

section>h2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  /* span 2 columns*/
}

section>img {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  /* span 2 rows */
}

section>span {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="">
  <h2>HEADING 2</h2>
  <span>11:44</span>
</section>
```

> I want the h2 to use the lower center space.
>
> I want the span to use the upper right space.
>
> The lower right space should be combined with the lowercenter in case the content of lowercenter overflows.

The `h2` area is supposed to span 2 columns so we extend it out into column 3.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is it you are trying to achieve? You can specify a width for a grid-column in px if you want and tell the image to be `max-width`